# Getting old website after hack (even using wget) - No proxies involved

Tags: proxy, hacking, apache-2.4

Our server was hacked and several pages were replaced. We manage to clean up everything. Currently if you access the website from anywhere using any browser the website shows correct and clean.

Only in the network of a particular university, every computer (any browser), keeps showing the hacked website. We have tried many things and it's very awkward:

- There is no proxy involved (checked for transparent proxies with whatismyproxy.com)
- If you rename the website on the server from index.php to index2.php, then the file is showed correctly.
- Refreshing the page on the browser will always appear on the apache log as a request with a correct 200 answer, but somewhere it's intercepted because on the browser the old page will show.
- We even tried using wget, with the same result, the old page is downloaded.

We have no idea where to look any more. How could we discover where the old page cached?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Without having specific knowledge about the University (i.e., is the old Web site being pulled from any network within the entire organization, or only from certain subnets within the University) this question is hard to answer.

This excerpt comes directly from "WhatIsMyProxy.com":

> Some proxy servers ("Anonymous" proxies) are configured to conceal their presence. We do attempt to reveal as much about them as we can, but if they do their job well we will not detect their presence. If the proxy you are using does not show up on the "Basic" check it can be reasonably assumed that other websites will not detect it either.

[Click here to view the entire FAQ page for WhatIsMyProxy.com](http://www.whatismyproxy.com/faq.php)

I would guess that the university is probably using a very stealthy transparent proxy. It's possible that the site you're using is simply not able to detect it.  I would especially consider this to be the case if the entire network (regardless of VLAN or location on campus) is affected.

Do you have any way to contact the network administrator for the university network directly? Perhaps they can shed some light on it for you.

Comment: We contacted the university administrators. They answered the following: this happens only to computers using NAT, not those having a static external ip, but they deny using any cache or proxy server.

Comment: That doesn't make sense ... (I'm not saying that isn't what they told you - just that it doesn't make any sense.)  All the internal computers have to use NAT to get on the public Internet (unless they're servers running Web services or something, but I don't think you'd be trying to pull up Web pages on a Server.  (I hope not anyway.) It is possible (but not likely) that they're using NAT internally ... but I can't think of any reason why they'd do that. Given the information, I would say the best option here is to just wait for their proxy cache to clear itself.  Sorry I don't have more info.

Comment: Light bulb:  What about this ... on your Web server, rename the new 'index.php' to 'main.php'.  Then, create a new 'index.php' that has a PHP header function (nothing else) that automatically redirects visitors to the site to the 'main.php' file.  I use that on one of our sites to redirect users from our '.com' domain to '.org'.  It's seamless and would force any proxy servers to load the new site.  Kind of a work-around, but it should work.